# How would I wire this tapped transformer welder?

Tags: current-source, current-transformer

I was gifted this old arc welder, w/o switches and the leads floating.
I asked this question on a welding forum also, but no response as of yet.

Dual 12 gage copper primaries
Dual 6 gage copper secondaries in series.
Originally there must have been 3 pushbutton selectors. No facility for on/off switch

3 pics of the x-former, the coil arrangement as given, and some inductance/resistance measurements.

[image]

[image: Core type]

[image]

[image]

These with a Fluke, but I will try an old very low ohms meter as ohming out 12 gauge copper has it's own issues.

I see that
coils 1&2 have logical value for inductance....
Coil 3 high value of resistance....

I saw a similar video where "pairs", 1&2, 3&4, 4&5 of coils get terminated/bridged on the switch lugs?

I've attached a pic of the welder and some sketches of tracing the primary coils

I would appreciate it, as this is a bit puzzling...

regards, and tia,
Nick

Comment: Being a welder, where is the high-current rectifier? Where is the load inductor? Need these also.

Comment: Rotate the diagrams so they display right way up. Are the numbers yours or marked on the leads? Clearly designate all wire sizes that you have determined. How have you determined primary and secondary? "two dual primaries and two dual secondaries" add up to four windings. A neat and orderly question with as many facts as you can establish and no assumptions or comments will have the best chance of getting answers.

Comment: Primary’s are higher R and you need Litz wire for secondary

Comment: Ok,some of the pics wont rotate, sorry.

Comment: This a simple AC welder, no rectifier/inductor. Primaries are smaeller gage in a welder, with thick secondaries wired to the electrode connections.  In the pic, the primaries are the top 2 coils. I've never seen a buzzbox with Litz wire secondaries (we're talking 50Hz, and over 200 A here...). The 3rd pic is what I've traced, the numbers are mine. The 4th pic is the same simplified, and that's what I'm asking. As I said, a video with a similar welder switches the "paired" wires I have shown.regards

Comment: https://youtu.be/3vcL-HDOIcE?t=290